# Android YUV_420_888 to RGBA with ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB NV21 and nio buffers in JNI

Tags: android, kotlin, java-native-interface, yuv, rgba

I work with YUV_420_888 image format (from camera) and I would like to convert it to RGBA on Android. I know there are many available soulutions but I would like to use the built-in ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB and do the buffer copy in JNI/NDK.

I know in this format Y,U,V planes are available and it is guaranteed that U and V planes will have the same pixelstride/rowstride and length and on some devices U and V might be overlapped.

For *simplicity* let's see the case when Y's pixelstride=1, rowstride=image width and UV's pixelstride=2 and rowstride=image width as well. Let the image dimension be 1920x1080

The issue is the following:

1. When I allocate a direct buffer in Kotlin its actual size is 7 bytes larger than the requested size (I figured out it is because of JVM's direct buffer alignment)
2. I fill this direct buffer in NDK, populate input allocation with this buffer, call ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB's forEach method and it will always create a "corrupted" output image. The very left columns on the left are actually the right side columns
3. If I fill a ByteArray in Kotlin and populate input allocation from it the output image is correct.

```
// JNI code
void nFillBuffer(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                jobject dest,
                jint width, jint height,
                jobject y, jobject u, jobject v,
                jint ySize, jint uSize, jint vSize,
                jint yRowStride,
                jint uvRowStride, jint uvPixelStride)
{
    jbyte* destPtr = (jbyte*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(dest);
    jbyte* yBuffer = (jbyte*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(y);
    jbyte* uBuffer = (jbyte*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(u);
    jbyte* vBuffer = (jbyte*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(v);

    int32_t pos = 0;

    // copy Y
    if (width == yRowStride)
    {
        pos = (width * height);
        memcpy(destPtr, yBuffer, pos);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int32_t i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
            memcpy(destPtr + pos, yBuffer + (i * yRowStride), width);
            pos += width;
        }
    }

    // is UV overlapped?
    if (uvRowStride == width && uvPixelStride == 2 && uBuffer == vBuffer + 1) {

        memcpy(destPtr + pos, vBuffer, vSize);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i < height / 2; ++i)
            for (int j=0; j < width / 2; ++j)
            {
                destPtr[pos++] = vBuffer[i*uvRowStride + j*uvPixelStride];
                destPtr[pos++] = uBuffer[i*uvRowStride + j*uvPixelStride];
            }
    }
}
```

It's being called from Kotlin in this code snippet

```
...
...
// Renderscript init
rs = RenderScript.create(context)
yuvToRGB =  ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs));
val yuvType: Type.Builder =
    Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs))
        .setX(width)
        .setY(height)
        .setYuvFormat(ImageFormat.NV21)

inputAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT)
yuvToRGB.setInput(inputAllocation);

nioBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(inputAllocation.bytesSize  /*width*height + ((width * height) / 2)*/)

val rgbType: Type.Builder =
    Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs))
        .setX(width)
        .setY(height)

outputAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT)
...
...
// Process input image 
val y = image.planes[0].buffer!!
val u = image.planes[1].buffer!!
val v = image.planes[2].buffer!!

val ySize = y.remaining()
val uSize = u.remaining()
val vSize = v.remaining()

val yRowStride = image.planes[0].rowStride;
val uvPixelStride = image.planes[1].pixelStride
val uvRowStride = image.planes[1].rowStride

assert(1 == image.planes[0].pixelStride)             // must be 1
assert(uvRowStride == image.planes[2].rowStride)     // must be equal
assert(uvPixelStride == image.planes[2].pixelStride) // must be equal
assert(uvPixelStride == 1 || uvPixelStride == 2)     // must be 1 or 2

// Native
nFillBuffer(
        nioBuffer,
        image.width, image.height,
        y, u, v,
        ySize, uSize, vSize,
        yRowStride,
        uvRowStride, uvPixelStride)

inputAllocation.copyFrom(nioBuffer.array())

// Workaround: copy the right size buffer (image is NOT corrupted)
// val nioCopy = ByteArray(ySize + vSize)
// nioBuffer[nioCopy, 0, ySize + vSize]
// inputAllocation.copyFrom(nioCopy)
// nioBuffer.rewind();

yuvToRGB.forEach(outputAllocation);
outputAllocation.copyTo(outputBitmap)
...
```

I tried to allocate smaller direct buffer as well but could not generate the correct output image. Is there any way to request the right size direct buffer or avoid the workaround copy code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am a little bit confused, here. You're saying `nioBuffer` is 7 bytes too large, correct? So you call `allocateDirect()` with a given value, and `nioBuffer.capacity()` is _larger_ than that value? And that's causing `inputAllocation.copyFrom()` to copy too much? Furthermore, 1920x1080 makes for a YUV buffer of 0x2F7600‬ bytes. That's alignable on a 256-byte boundary, much less an 8-byte boundary.

Comment: Maybe this is related to a known bug when creating YUV allocations with USAGE_SCRIPT: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37130136

Comment: I checked my code again and add some extra logging. It seems the nio buffer's capacity is the expected value.
But nioBuffer.array()'s length is 8 bytes longer and it can generate extra bytes at allocation copyFrom method.

Comment: Maybe you would have better luck if your `nFillBuffer()` routine filled a `Bitmap` instead of a `ByteBufferDirect`.